# Is it possible to create a sub parser under a sub parser with python argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to create a tool that accepts the following format but cant quite figure out if `argparse` can do this.

Example Usage:

```
./myscript account account-a --create
./myscript account account-b --delete
./myscript account account-a domain example.com --delete
./myscript account account-b domain example.com --create
./myscript account account-a node 10 --start
./myscript account account-b node 10 --stop
```

Where `account-a` and `account-b` can be any account name, and `example.com` and node `10` are any value.

Comment: Yes, subparsers may have subparsers.  That said, it is hard to tell from your examples which strings are subparser commands and which are other arguments (positional or flagged).   Just create some simple scripts and experiment.

Comment: I have been trying to figure this out which is why I have asked here :(. `account` is a sub menu, `account-a` is the positional argument, `domain` is a sub menu of the account and `example.com` is the positional. The idea is to be able to run `./myscript account someAccount domain -h` and see the help for the domain sub sub menu.

Comment: Normally we ask posters to include the `argparse` code that they are using, at least as far as they've gotten.  It is much easier to suggest fixes to existing code, than to write an example from scratch.

Comment: Unfortunately I would normally post the code but it is a closed project and I am under an NDA

Comment: Often a toy example is better than a real world one.  We want focus on one problem, without unnecessary details.